# Is there a way in Google Sheets to order blank cells first?

Tags: google-sheets, sorting, google-sheets-query

When I sort a column in Google Spreadsheets, the blanks always seem to sink to the bottom.  Can I have rows with blank cels be organized first / highest?

Alternatively, is there a function wherein I can specify a sort order based on an array of options, like

```
[
  [1,''],
  [2,'i'],
  [3,'x']
]
```

where `1,2,3` is the sort order DESC.  the string is the `char` to match and associate with that sort order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you have any way to control the sort order directly, other than ascending or descending, so suggest a lookup table and a helper column (to determine the sort order) with a formula in that such as:

```
 =if(B1="",1,vlookup(left(B1,1),E:F,2,0))
```

where ColumnB is the one to be sorted, ColumnE the sort order and ColumnF a number starting at `1` and incrementing by one for each row.

Answer (score 4):

One easy way to make the blank cells appear at the top of the sheet when sorted is to enter an apostrophe `'` in the empty cells.

The apostrophe `'` will not be displayed in the cell, so it will continue to *appear* to be a blank cell however when you sort in ascending or descending order, it will put the pseudo-blank cell either at the top or at the bottom of the sheet.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative regarding blanks sinking to the bottom is to use QUERY, where they float to the top. So starting with:

[image: WA67363 example]

this formula in D1:

```
=query(A1:A3,"Select * order by A")
```

will return a blank in D1, `i` in D2 and `x` in D3.